# Error al usar Twitter Login - Firebase Auth: Unable to process request due to missing initial state

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-auth, twitter-api

Soy nuevo en programación y tengo el siguiente error al intentar hacer un login con el paquete twitter_login ^4.2.3 usando Flutter, GetX y Firebase Auth.

Cuando llamo el boton para hacer el login en twitter me abre la pantalla de autorización de twitter "api.twitter.com" y cuando le doy al boton "Autorizar la aplicación" me sale el siguiente error: Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared.

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar, este es el código de la función:

```
void signInWithTwitter() async {
    try {
      final twitterLogin = TwitterLogin(
        apiKey: apiKey,
        apiSecretKey: apiSecretKey,
        redirectURI: 'https://myapp-xxxxx.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler',
      );

      final authResult = await twitterLogin.login();
      final twitterAuthCredential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: authResult.authToken!,
        secret: authResult.authTokenSecret!,
      );
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(twitterAuthCredential);
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("About Twitter", 'Login Message',
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          titleText: const Text(
            'Login Twitter Failed',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          messageText: Text(
            e.toString(),
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ));
    }
  }
```